# jest test async class method

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
class person {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
  fetchPersonData() {
    fetch(api).then((return response) => {
      return response;
    })
  }
 async initializePerson() {
   const data = await fetchPersonData();
 }
```

}

I'm trying to write a test for initializePerson function but it doesn't get called.

```
  test("pass initializePerson", async( ) => {
      const personInstance = new person();
      let spy = jest.spyOn(personInstance, "initializePerson").mockImplementationOnce(async () => {
        return mock;
      });
    await personInstance.initializePerson();
    expect(spy).toBeCalledTimes(1);

  });
```

Comment: Why would you want to spy on a method you're calling upfront? What do you want to test?

Comment: @Christian test initialize is calling and passing

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes.

1. `(return response)` is wrong.
2. You're spying the method which you're calling. It doesn't make any sense. Spy methods which you've used inside the methods before calling the actual method.

I think you're looking for something like this.

```
class Person {
  constructor() {...}
  
  fetchPersonData() {
    return fetch(api).then(response => response.json())
  }

  async initializePerson() {
    const data = await fetchPersonData();
  }
}
```

and test.js

```
test("pass initializePerson", async () => {
    const personInstance = new Person();
    const fetchPersonDataSpy = jest.spyOn(personInstance, "fetchPersonData").mockResolvedValue({...})
    await personInstance.initializePerson();
    expect(fetchPersonDataSpy).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

If you want test the other method and mock the [fetch](https://www.leighhalliday.com/mock-fetch-jest), read this article. This will help you!

Comment: sorry, the response part was just a typo mistake here. the test is passing now but coverage still showing initializePerson is not running.

Comment: you might need to do [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/cli#--coverageboolean) to get the coverage report. I can't assume, what you did for the coverage

Comment: I have a coverage report. it just looks like initializePerson is not running

Comment: Then how you're test passing, If `initializePerson` is not running. Add more information what you're doing in the question, so we can do something about it.

Comment: constructor is called so it's passing. but initialize function not called